# Jenkins: Graphical view plugin that monitors scheduled jobs

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

I've used Delivery and Build Pipeline View plugins to graphically view a set of jobs that are linked via completion or conditional triggers, but I have found that these views do not show scheduled downstream completions (as in they stay grey as if they weren't executed when in fact they were).

**Example**: JobA is scheduled for 8:00am and JobB is scheduled for 12:00pm, if JobA was completed successfully, every day.

I am wondering if anyone knows of an existing plugin that can accommodate for this type of job monitoring.